# Linking problems with nix package manager and termux

Tags: ld, nix, termux

I tried to install the nix package manager on an Android device with termux.

When I try to execute the nix applicatives (for instance nix-store or nix-env) I get the following error

```
/nix/store/y9mfv3sx75mbfibf1zna1kq9v98fk2nb-nix-1.11.16/bin/nix-env:
error while loading shared libraries: 
/nix/store/kfk65xrfzndyyz6if5fxk4wrwz76h2lh-glibc-2.25-49/lib/libc.so: 
invalid ELF header
```

The file seems to be a script for the GNU linker, so I'm wondering what is the problem, could it be that termux's version of ld is unable to correctly interpret GNU Linker's scripts?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:** It seems that if unset the LD_PRELOADED and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables the nix-applications work fine. Problem is that in doing so termux cannot lunch any other non nix application, such as bash for instance.

Comment: Hmm... does your Android device conform to the `nix` supported platforms? See https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-supported-platforms

Comment: You're using hydra-built ARM aarch64 binaries (tested with `nix-store -r /nix/st...n/nix-env` and `file /nix/st...n/nix-env`). Which Android device are you using and does it support this instruction set? An unofficial armv7 port is also available. See https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NixOS_on_ARM

Comment: I am using the aarch64 architecture and th funny thing is that if I unset the LD's variables the nix-apps work fine, the problem is that in doing that bash stop working due to how termux works.

Comment: What about creating a script which unsets `LD_PRELOADED` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` prior to launching the Nix app. If that works, you can create a "wrapper" Nix package for the Nix app.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosaE there would still remain the problem that one couldn't exec application like bash through the nix-commands (for instance with nix-shell and nix-channel).